# How to make this accordion open with a link to an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, accordion

I really love this accordion example on the W3Schools site-

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol

How could the functionality be extended to open it via a link on the same page to an anchor tag inside a panel?

Comment: The policy on Stack Overflow is to never oblige people to go to another site in order to have all the information they need - in case the linked page no longer exist in a few years, making this question useless. Make sure you're allowed to paste code you put here though! Try to make a minimalist example here and show us what you've tried.

Comment: To follow up on @JacqueGoupil advice, read on how to make a [mcve]